# Vmware: Mouse pointer stops for a sec when changing focus to guest

Tags: mouse, linux-mint, vmware-workstation

**Host OS:** Windows 7 x64 (up2date)

**Guest OS:** Linux Mint xfce LTS (maya) (x64)

Vmware Workstation 9.0.3

VMware Tools is installed and seems to work.

**Problem description:**

When my mouse pointer moves in or out of the guest screen (in full screen too with vmware panel at the top) the mouse pointer stops for a sec at the border. Afterwards I can move the pointer further and it's automatically grabbed/ungrabbed. This is happening every time I enter/leave guest screen.

In my Xubuntu guest VM I can move the mouse pointer in and outside the screen without a delay. How can I have the same behavior in my Linux Mint guest system?

P.S.: I'm using a Synaptic touchpad.

Comment: Does this delay happen if you uninstall VMware Tools?

Comment: It's the same behavior, if vmware tools are not installed. So my guess is, that they are not correctly installed?
I get the same behavior on a fresh Xubuntu installation, but my old one is still working fine.

Comment: If this happens on a fresh install, logic says that VMware Tools are not to blame. I would wildly guess that in your "old one still working fine" you have maybe installed a version of VMware Tools that avoids the problem, but that newer versions don't.

Comment: I copied the install directory vmware tools of my running vm to my new vm and tried to install it again. But still not working

Comment: Then it has probably something to do with newer Linux versions, but no idea what, maybe a driver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is, that every time I change focus numlock is changed too.

**Background**

The touchpad software of Dell (I guess it's synaptic) has a so called TouchGuard feature(I think its enabled by default), which prevents using the touchpad mousepointer while typing on the keyboard.
It seems, that vmware is calling the numlock key every time I switch. So every time TouchGuard thinks "oh he is typing, mouse has to stop".

My other old VM works, because numlock simply doesn't have to change.

**Solutions**

- Either change the numlock so that guest and host have both numlock on or off.
- Or disable TouchGuard in your touchpad software configuration.

Update:
Capslock key may obviously also have the same issue.

Comment: I had the same issue and toggling numlock within my guest Ubuntu system did the trick. Thanks for getting to the bottom of this, since I would not have thought of it.

Comment: Well, I faced the same issue, after researching a lot came across this  and solved my problem, Couldn't even tell what was the problem before, thanks.

Comment: Never would have suspected numlock. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a pointer integration issue. Have you seen this guide? http://youtu.be/07vA52Oxzos

Comment: I installed it already this way and most other VMware tools feature are working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Just go to unity mode once, and exit it. then after mouse will not stick during  changing focus in borders of VM.
have fun...

Comment: To be honest what I did will make Numlock and capslock of VM and main OS the same and this solves the problem. :) regards